(Unethical) building contractor billing practices?
I have employed a building contractor for over 6 months now for build work on our home. Before I went to contract, I signed off on varied hourly labour rates depending on skilled levels which I have up until now interpreted the people getting billed at these hourly rates are direct employees of the building contractor and on his direct payroll. I say that because I also singed off on other rates including sub contractors + % commission, materials + % commission etc. standard stuff. But it has just materialised that one of these persons (and perhaps even more of them) being billed to us under an hourly rate is an actual private limited company - building services company filing under the Nature of business (SIC) 41100 - Development of building projects. Why would our building contractor disguise this one person as one of his own employees by charging me an hourly rate for him when he is clearly a sub contractor (?) and will likely be billing an invoice to our contractor for his works undertaken? Any and all feedback welcome. Thanks!

I know multiple building contractors whose "employees" are actually subcontractors because it works out better for tax purposes. Does it really matter to you if the main contractor sends the subcontractor a paycheque or if he pays a bill? He's profiting off of them either way.

It's a bit confusing! The building contractor himself is billing us hourly for his contractor services, but we also signed off on his other hourly rates ie.  tradesman builder, skilled labour, foreman etc.  which we do not have a problem with. But one of the guys being billed weekly under his tradesman builder rates is actually a builder who owns his own building company completely separate to our building contractors company. Shouldn't we just be paying this tradesman builder the sub contractor rate + % as to me he is in fact a sub contractor who will be invoicing our contractor for his time?

Perhaps I'm over thinking it... I just find it odd that he bills us all the other sub contractor invoices such as the joiners and roofers invoices + the agreed % commission but not this builder.

I don't see how this is a question of ethics. You hired a contractor. You have a contract with said contractor. How and who they hire, fire, and pay their workers and sub-contractors is immaterial to you and shouldn't be any of your concern.

Obvious question - would you be paying more or less for this person if he was being billed to you with the hourly rate for a subcontractor?

Also this question would be better on our [money.se] site.

FWIW - this is super common in NZ, not unethical.

Before you go too far down this hole, remember that you have hired a building contractor. That person is the one responsible for the business practices and is to be held accountable for the final product, your house and the price. The specifics of business relationships between that building contractor and employees or subcontractors is that person's business. The real questions need to be about the quality of the work, about whether the design is being followed, and is the building contractor still under budget for the work that they were hired to do.
Asking the building contractor about subcontractors posing as employees might be done simply as a "curiosity question" rather than questioning the ethics of that subcontractor and by implication, the ethics of your building contractor.
